# entering text in edit text moves textview below keyboard android

Tags: android

I have a layout with edit text(multiline upto 1000 characters) and textview that displays count of characters. As user enters the text in editext, textview should be displayed just above keyboard and should display count.

My problem is, as user enters the text in edittext, the textview moves below the keyboard as characters grow. TextView should stay above the keyboard and editext should scroll in the available space.

can any one help me on this?

Comment: Please share your relevant layout XML file.

Comment: use android:minLines in EditText

Comment: post your xml code here . what have you done till now ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the minLines attribute if you wish to keep the text in the edit text in one line. Furthermore, it depends on what you are using as your soft keyboard input, which is declared in your manifest file. Depending on the input type, the keyboard will float to various places.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i cannot use minLines becoz i dont know how many lines will be used for different screen sizes. input type i am using is "typeMultiLine".